# Mysql Query Taking lot of time to fetch data

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I am fetching data from multiple table having 600 thousand of records. But is taking a lot and lot of time to fetch it.
Please let me know how can i shorten the time to fetch it.
I also have used the LIMIT case, but still no improvement.

My query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
tf_history.thefind_id, 
tf_product.product_id, 
tf_product.`name`, 
tf_product.product_url, 
tf_product.image_tpm, 
tf_product.image_thefind, 
tf_product.image_accuracy, 
(SELECT MIN(tf_h.price)
 FROM tf_history AS tf_h
 WHERE tf_h.thefind_id = tf_history.thefind_id) as price, 
oc_product.price AS priceTPM
FROM tf_product
LEFT JOIN tf_history ON tf_product.product_id = tf_history.product_id 
                     AND tf_product.thefind_id = tf_history.thefind_id
LEFT JOIN oc_product ON tf_product.product_id = oc_product.product_id 
WHERE  tf_product.product_id = @product_id
```

MY table:

```
tf_history

history_id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
thefind_id  int(11) NO          
product_id  int(11) NO          
price   decimal(15,4)   NO          
date    datetime    NO          

AND
tf_product

thefind_id  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
product_id  int(11) NO          
name    varchar(255)    NO          
store_id    int(11) NO          
product_url varchar(255)    NO          
image_tpm   varchar(255)    NO          
image_thefind   varchar(255)    NO          
image_accuracy  int(3)  NO          
date    datetime    NO
```

But when i use this query:

```
SELECT * from tf_history
```

i got the result in 0.641s, then what can be the issue?
When there was less record the, first query was running smoothly.

Comment: What are the table definitions?  What indices do you have?  What kind of hardware are you running on?  What is "lot and lot of time"?  Seconds?  Minutes?  Hours?

Comment: My hardware is Dual Core

Comment: And your disk IO system is... floppy disk?  SATA?  RAID?  NAS?  How much memory compared to amount of data?  All of these things can matter.

Comment: Thanks @EricJ. for asking indices, by that i remember that i forget to use one..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using index will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the result, by using Indexes

Answer (score 0):

Move the subselect column into the join

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
th.thefind_id, 
tp.product_id, 
tp.`name`, 
tp.product_url, 
tp.image_tpm, 
tp.image_thefind, 
tp.image_accuracy, 
th.price, 
op.price AS priceTPM
FROM tf_product tp
LEFT JOIN (SELECT thefind_id, product_id, MIN(price) as price
           FROM tf_history
           group by thefind_id, product_id) th ON tp.product_id = th.product_id
                                               AND tp.thefind_id = th.thefind_id
LEFT JOIN oc_product op ON tp.product_id = op.product_id 
WHERE  tp.product_id = @product_id
```